# Find gauge factor of a strain gauge

Tags: strain-gage

I have recently bought a few strain gauges (BX 120-3AA) of resistance 120 ohm. As I bought it from a local market I do not have any datasheet of it.

1. How do I find the gauge factor?
   I guess it's typically around 2.1. I think one way is to paste the SG on a cantilever structure and measure by applying some load to it. I find the strain theoretically and find the gauge factor from it.
   Is there any other way anyone else has tried?
2. The strain limit is given as 2%. Does this mean it can measure up to +/-20,000 µε?

Answer (score 1):

https://www.aliexpress.us/item/2251832101378575.html?gatewayAdapt=glo2usa4itemAdapt&_randl_shipto=US lists the "sensitivity" as

Sensitivity coefficient : 2.06 ~ 2.12

2% strain limit means you can increase the length of the gauge by 2% max before it's damaged.  The force that is required to do so will have everything to do with the geometry of what it's mounted to, where the applied force is, ....